# Abbreviation or word like "cc'd", but referring to someone in the "to:" field

Tags: single-word-requests, abbreviations, business-language, email

I'm looking for an abbreviation or single word which functions just like the abbreviation "cc'd", except explicitly refers to someone who is in the `To:` field of an email, and *not* the `CC:` or `BCC:` field.

For example:

> `To: michael.scott@dundermifflin.com, scrantonbranch@dundermifflin.com`
>
> `CC: nybranch@dundermifflin.com`
>
> We're bring in Michael Scott (cc'd*) as the new manager of the project.

*Except the cc'd in the above sentence would be replaced with the word/abbreviation I'm looking for--because Mr. Scott is not cc'd, he's included as a primary receiver of the email.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410627/how-to-use-the-term-carbon-copy-in-business-emails) is concerned with how to, "convey the idea that someone's email address is in the box named "Cc" ". It is similar, but does not address the preferred way to address someone that is in the `To:` field as opposed to the `CC:` field.

Comment: Well I would fix it by putting them in the CC box

Comment: If "cc'd" works in the first place, what would be wrong with "to'd", please? Don't they follow - or break - the same rules?

Comment: The people in the "To:" field are *addressees*.

Answer (score 2):

I’d rephrase since it seems weird (potentially rude) to refer to someone in the *to:* list in the third person.

If he is not addressed in the e-mail then *cc:* not *to:* list seems correct, and your question disappears.

Perhaps something like :

> Hi folks,
>   We have some changes planned etc etc
>
> Michael - We're bringing you in as the new manager of the project.
>
> Peter- you will need to assist Michael to ...

[Perhaps this should be a comment not an answer!]

Answer (score 0):

You might use the acronym **RCPT**, which means **recipient**, this is according to [The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RCPT) (note that the acronym has some other listed meaning as well).